# Showing error in using $ symbol

Tags: python-2.7, web.py

I'm using web.py in code.py file when i call submit.render to a html file and it is showing error for using $ symbol in javascript for getting json file. How can i use $ symbol in code.py calling html file.

Answer (score 1):

Within a web.py template, double '$' to escape it, or if it's jquery, just use jquery's alternate calling syntax `jQuery()` instead of `$()`.